# Error loading panel plugin TypeError: r.PanelPlugin is not a constructor (Grafana)

Tags: grafana

I am developing a Grafana plugin. I am using 6.3.5 version of grafana. I cloned this code from github and build the grafana using

```
go run build.go setup
go run build.go setup
```

I cloned the simple-react-panel code from [react plugin](https://github.com/grafana/simple-react-panel). And placed it in the plugin folder and build the plugin using `yarn build`. After that i start the grafana server and plugin works fine. I have done this on the windows machine.

Now i have to run it on linux machine. I have a grafana 6.3.5 installed on a VM. I cloned the same `simple-react-pnel` plugin in the plugins folder of grafana. After that i build the plugin using `yarn build`. plugin does get build. Now when i start the grafana server, i can see my plugin but when i click on the plugin i get the error `Panel plugin not found: myorgid-simple-panel`. In the console i have the error

```
Error loading panel plugin TypeError: r.PanelPlugin is not a constructor
at Module.eval (module.js:1)
at n (module.js:1)
at eval (module.js:1)
at eval (module.js:1)
at o (system.js:4)
at system.js:4
at system.js:4
at S (system.js:4)
at E (system.js:4)
at system.js:4
```

Issue is that same plugin works fine with grafana on windows system but does not work on linux system. Grafana does show this plugin as installed when i get the list of installed plugin through grafana-cli.

[image]
What can be the possible issue ?

After running `yarn install` i get this:

```
yarn install v1.21.1
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by t                                                                                                                                                             
ools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoi                                                                                                                                                             
d resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this                                                                                                                                                              
warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check.                                                                                                                                                              
Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@grafana/toolkit > @grafana/ui > @grafana/slate-react > slate-react-pla                                                                                                                                                             
ceholder@0.2.9" has unmet peer dependency "slate-react@>=0.22.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 34.68s.
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug raised about this

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/20338

However, to why it built on windows and not linux would need more investigation. Are you sure the grafana version was the same ?

Comment: Yes, grafana version is the same. . .  grafana version is 6.3.5

Comment: What version of grafana toolkit do you have on each environment ?

Comment: 6.6.0. .  added from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grafana/toolkit link

Comment: its not working even with grafana toolkit 6.3.2 . . . Interesting thing is that, this issue is only appearing for react plugin, angular plugin is working fine.

Comment: Do you do a ```yarn install``` first to resolve dependencies ? would be interesting to see its output

Comment: added in the question description

Comment: TS2305: Module '"../node_modules/@grafana/ui"' has no exported member 'PanelPlugin'. . ..  getting this error with grafana toolkit 6.4.0 @tomgalpin

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days i managed to resolve the issue. Issue was with the versions of `Grafana Toolkit` and `Grafana UI` packages. As i am using an older version of Grafana so, i have to use older packages of `Grafana Toolkit` and `Grafana UI`. I succeeded in resolving the issue by using the following versions.

```
Grafana Toolkit : 6.4.4
Grafana UI : 6.3.2
```

I got them from [Grafana Toolkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grafana/toolkit/v/6.4.4) and [Grafana UI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grafana/ui/v/6.3.2).